# Removing the </p> tag from grep output

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, grep

I have I bash script that will find phones numbers inside .htm or .html files in a directory (or recursivly down if I want it) to find phone numbers in the format (ddd)ddd-dddd or ddd-ddd-dddd (Where d represents a digit).

This is my code:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*\(html\|htm\)$" | xargs grep '\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[-]\?[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}'
```

The output is:

```
./dash_only_phone.htm:800-555-1212</p>
./paren_phone.htm:(800)555-1212</p>
```

I was wondering how I would change the grep command to remove the html p tag printout at the end.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `grep` supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, as do GNU and OS X `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})-?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}(?=</p>)'
```

Note the changes in escaping (which are similar to or the same as for `grep -E`).

Comment: This works perfectly. I'm testing this in a Ubuntu server that has GNU grep. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome, saves one additional piping to sed command. I wasn't aware about this experimental `--perl-regexp` option in grep, thanks a lot for enlightening us.

Comment: @anubhava: While GNU warns of it being experimental, Apple doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the output through a `sed` filter to remove it, as in the following transcript:

```
pax$ echo './dash_only_phone.htm:800-555-1212</p>' | sed 's?</p>$??'
./dash_only_phone.htm:800-555-1212
```

This will get rid of any `</p>` sequences that appear at the end of a line.

Comment: This works nice, but how would I apply this to my grep command?

Comment: @Destroyer: Quickest solution without having to think too much, run the whole thing in a subshell and apply the `sed` filter to it: `( <your entire command here> ) 2>&1 | sed 's?</p>$??'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `-o` switch to get the IP

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*\(html\|htm\)$" | xargs grep -o '\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[-]\?[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}'
```

Comment: After using the man pages on grep and reading the -o command, I like it. Thanks for showing it to me! Another great solution.